# Converting Array to UL LI

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, html-lists

I can't for the life of me convert my array to a nested UL LI tree, I've been attempting it all day but there must be some flaw that I cannot spot (probably because my array isn't a very simple one).

Basically the array takes the form:

```
$array = array(
  "0" => array(
    "0" => array("letter" => "A", "data" => "123"), 
    "1" => array(
      "0" => array(
        "0" => array("letter" => "B", "data" => "123"), 
        "1" => array(
          "0" => array(
            "0" => array("letter" => "C", "data" => "123")
          )
        )
      ), 
      "1" => array(
        "0" => array("letter" => "D", "data" => "123"), 
        "1" => array(
          "0" => array(
            "0" => array("letter" => "E", "data" => "123")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

**Explaining Array Above**

The arrays come in pairs - the first number being the group, and the second being the row. The above has 3 columns (or levels as I call them) and there is only has one 'group'.

So `[0][0]` would be group 0, first row, `[0][1][0][0]` would be the second row of level one, but is the first row of level 2, and so one.

Where basically I want the result to appear as follows (for the example above):

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
        <ul class="initial">
            <li>A</li>
            <li class="top">
                <ul class="wrap">
                    <li>
                        <ul class="inner">
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li class="top">
                                <ul class="wrap">
                                    <li>
                                        <ul class="inner">
                                            <li>C</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="end"><a class="add">Add</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ul class="inner">
                            <li>D</li>
                            <li class="top">
                                <ul class="wrap">
                                    <li>
                                        <ul class="inner">
                                            <li>E</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="end"><a class="add">Add</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="end"><a class="add">Add</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="end"><a class="add">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically, an 'add' appears at the end of each node branch (last list item within 'wrap' class).

I've done the following so far, but I feel it isn't correct at all, and doesn't work correctly if additional nodes were added or nodes were removed.

```
function recursion($data, $level){

    $skip = array_key_exists('data', $data[0]) ? 0 : 1;

    if($skip == 0){
        $level++;
        if($level !== 1){
            $out .= "<li>\n";
        }
        if($level == 1){
            $out .= "<ul class='initial'>\n";
        } else {
            $out .= "<ul class='inner'>\n";
        }
    }
    $count = 0;
    $loop_count = 0;
    $show_end = 0;
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $loop_count++;
        if(is_array($value) && array_key_exists('data', $value)){
            $count++;

            $out .= ($skip == 0) ? "<li>" : "";

            if($value['data'] == "123"){
                $out .= $value['letter'];
            }

            if(!is_array($data[($key+1)][0])){
                $out .= "</li>\n";
                $out .= "<li class=\"end\"><a class=\"add\">Add</a></li>\n";

                $out .= "</ul>\n";
                $out .= "</li>\n";
                $out .= "</ul>\n";
                $out .= "</li>\n";

                $out .= "<li class=\"end\"><a class=\"add\">Add</a></li>\n";

                $show_end = 1;
            }
            $last_key = $key;
        } else if(is_array($value)){
            $out.= recursion($value, $level);
        }
        if($show_end == 1){
            $out .= "</ul>\n";
        }
        if(is_array($value) && array_key_exists('data', $value) && !is_array($data[($key+1)])){
            $out .= "</li>\n";
        }
        if($show_end == 1 && count($data) !== $count){
            $out .= "<li>\n";
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Output of

```
 print_r($array, true)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [letter] => A
                    [data] => 123
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [letter] => B
                                            [data] => 123
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [letter] => C
                                                            [data] => 123
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [letter] => D
                                            [data] => 123
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [letter] => E
                                                            [data] => 123
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can it be in javascript? (using jQuery?)

Comment: Spend some more time explaining your data structure in your question, IMO.

Comment: @Michael Javascript? Potentially - belongs as it can display the tree correctly

Comment: @drrcknlsn i'll attempt that above

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo "<pre>" . print_r($array,true) . "</pre>";`?

Comment: @DavidThomas adding that first for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your array structure matches the HTML you have shown?  I tweaked the array and came up with this function that seems to work.

```
function build_list($array, $level=0)
{
    foreach($array as $group)
    {
        echo '<li>';
        if(isset($group['letter']))
        {
            echo $group['letter'];
        }
        else            
        {
            $class = 'wrap';
            if($level%2 == 1)
            {
                $class = 'inner';
            }
            echo '<ul class="' . $class . '">';
            build_list($group, $level+1);
            if($class == 'wrap')
            {
                echo '<li class="end"><a class="add">Add</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

Here are my changes to the array:

```
$array = 
array
(
    array("letter" => "A", "data" => "123"), //li
    array //li ul
    (
        array //li ul
        (
            array("letter" => "B", "data" => "123"), //li
            array //li ul
            (
                array //li ul
                (
                    array("letter" => "C", "data" => "123")
                )
            )
        ),
        array
        (
            array("letter" => "D", "data" => "123"), 
            array
            (
                array
                (
                    array("letter" => "E", "data" => "123")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then to call it:

```
<ul class="inital">
<?php
build_list($array);
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The inner HTML should match up with that, there is an additional <ul> and <li> prior to the `initial` <ul> which I seemed to have missed off (I have these pre-filed, so apologies for not realising these were missing - will update post), so good spot! While your array looks much nicer than mine (and doesn't work with the above), is there an easy way to transform it so it can simply work like the above? [I've already put the generating and serializing storage together, so as long as I can strip out the index numbers, it should work]

Comment: Of course your array is the same, apart from that your array is equal to $array[0] from mine :P

Comment: The main difference between our array's (besides being $array[0]) is the depth of B. The nesting from A -> B is not equal to the nesting from B -> C in the array, but it is in your HTML. Does that make sense?

Comment: That is a bit weird, I think it may have been altered during an edit (that another user kindly modified) and an extra array popped in...

Comment: It does seem that your solution works perfectly, thanks. One thing though, would it be possible to only show the 'add' on the last cycle of that level, for example, if we added 'F' on the same level as 'D' (before or after 'E') - add only appears below 'F' and not 'D' (this shouldn't affect 'B`s' 'add' in anyway though).

Comment: can you just add it after the initial function call?